# Why does fetch return even after catching an error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, fetch

I'm trying to write a generic `getData()` function that I can call with different urls, and taking different actions when data is returned from the server.

```js
function getData(url){
        console.log("loading: " + url)
        return fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("received response")
                console.log(response.status)
                if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300)                 { 
                    console.log("url returned data...")
                    return response.json()
                } else {
                    console.log("url did not return data...")
                    throw new Error("The url did not return data")
                }
             })
             .catch((err) => {return err})
}
    
getData("notexisting.json")
         .then(data => console.log("success!!"))
         .catch(err => console.log("error!!"))
```

The problem is that this code snippet shows no error even if the url does not exist. Also, the two `console.logs` inside the `if` statements are never reached, and the `getData()` function is always successful... even if there IS an error...

Comment: The `.catch()` inside `getData()` doesn't throw an exception, so the `.catch()` call *outside* the function won't be invoked.

Comment: Ah, when I replace `return err` with `throw err` it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove `catch` statement from `getData` and it will work just as you expected it

```
function getData(url){
        console.log("loading: " + url)
        return fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("received response")
                console.log(response.status)
                if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300)                 { 
                    console.log("url returned data...")
                    return response.json()
                } else {
                    console.log("url did not return data...")
                    throw new Error("The url did not return data")
                }
             })
}

getData("notexisting.json")
         .then(data => console.log("success!!"))
         .catch(err => console.log("error!!"))

// output is error!!
```

Comment: No, it always returns succesful, even if the url does not exist or there is some other error, the console always logs "Success!!"

Comment: Ah... brilliant! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From docs:

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status
>   even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve
>   normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on
>   network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

I prefer using libraries like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) because I prefer its behavior against standard fetch (that has to be polyfilled anyway).

Comment: That's why I include the `if` statement, to see if the status is OK/200 and only then continue code execution.